# Using JSTL function in JSF

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, jstl

i want to use the **JSTL function** contains in **JSF2**
here's what i tried but the condition always evaluates to false, i think i am missing something:

```
<c:forEach items="#{myBean.toSendCheckBoxes}" var="entry" varStatus="loop">                             

               <input type="checkbox" name="myArray" value="#{entry.value}" />

               <c:choose>

                 <c:when test="#{fn:contains(entry.key,'g')}">
                   <ice:graphicImage url="/resources/images/image1.bmp" />
                   <b>#{entry.key}</b>                      
                 </c:when>

                 <c:otherwise>
                   <ice:graphicImage url="/resources/images/image2.bmp" />
                   <span>#{entry.key}</span>
                 </c:otherwise>



               </c:choose>

            </c:forEach>
```

if there's another JSF way to accomplish that, would be very nice to mention it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More JSFish way to do it would be

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myBean.toSendCheckBoxes}" var="entry" varStatus="loop">                             

  <input type="checkbox" name="myArray" value="#{entry.value}" />

  <ui:fragment rendered="#{fn:contains(entry.key,'g')}">
    <ice:graphicImage url="/resources/images/image1.bmp" />
    <b>#{entry.key}</b>                      
  </ui:fragment>

  <ui:fragment rendered="#{!fn:contains(entry.key,'g')}">
    <ice:graphicImage url="/resources/images/image2.bmp" />
    <span>#{entry.key}</span>
  </ui:fragment>

</ui:repeat>
```

or even

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myBean.toSendCheckBoxes}" var="entry" varStatus="loop">                             

  <input type="checkbox" name="myArray" value="#{entry.value}" />

  <ice:graphicImage url="#{fn:contains(entry.key,'g') ? '/resources/images/image1.bmp' : '/resources/images/image2.bmp'}" />
  <span class="#{fn:contains(entry.key,'g') ? 'bold-style' : ''}">#{entry.key}</span>
</ui:repeat>
```

but I would expect your condition to evaluate properly nevertheless.

Comment: ui repeat doesn't work with me i don't know why, always prints empty div, is that related to map initialization ? i initialize it in the @postconstruct.

Comment: @Msaleh it won't work with nested c: tags for sure but otherwise should be fine. Without posting your entire markup with ui:repeat I cannot tell more. Also mind using input as html tag wont let you edit the model if it's your intention. You should use h:inputText then.

Answer (score 1):

I use `t:dataList` (myfaces tomahawk `xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"`) for looping over elements to have correct identifier generation and `rendered` attribute for different displaying of elements in the list.

```
<t:dataList layout="simple" value="#{myBean.toSendCheckBoxes}" var="entry">                             
    <input type="checkbox" name="myArray" value="#{entry.value}" />
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{fn:contains(entry.key,'g')}">
            <ice:graphicImage url="/resources/images/image1.bmp" />
            <b>#{entry.key}</b>                      
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not fn:contains(entry.key,'g')}">
            <ice:graphicImage url="/resources/images/image2.bmp" />
            <span>#{entry.key}</span>
        </h:panelGroup>
</t:dataList>
```

I've had issues with dynamic element rendering (show/hide rows) within `ui:repeat`, so I had to use `t:dataList` instead.

Comment: This is not true. Neither ui:repeat or t:dataList generate components in each iteration. You are confusing ui:repeat with c:forEach.

Comment: @mrembisz I've had problems before with `ui:repeat` element, specifically with id generation within nested loops and dynamic content like in the example. And yes, I may be confused about the reasons of the problem. I modify the appropriate part of my answer.

Comment: ui:repeat indeed was (at least as of mojarra 2.0.6) bugged when nested. It did not manage state of the nested UIRepeat component properly resulting in storing state under id's with UIRepeat's indices. In such case t:dataList could be helpful. But otherwise getting a heavy tomahawk suite would be an overkill in my opinion.